# Python HTML POST with requests

Tags: python, html, python-requests

I would like to download some weather information with python from: http://idojarasbudapest.hu/archivalt-idojaras, but I can not see the necessary informations until I don't press the submit button "Mehet". There is two information which I have to submit: Year ('ev'), and month ('ho').

As I understand, I have to POST a request with two parameters: 'ev' and 'ho', then the website should "send me" the requested informations.

The following code which I wrote, prints the original website's html code, not the requested one.

```
import requests

data= {'ev': '2016','ho': 'Január'}
r = requests.post('http://idojarasbudapest.hu/archivalt-idojaras', data=data)

print (r.text)
```

The html form looks like this:

[image: The html form]

Any idea, how to fix this?
Thanks for any answer or suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From inspecting the post request sent by the browser when the "Mehet" button is pressed, I see that the arguments sent in the POST request have a different form than the ones you are posting via `requests`.

[image: Firefox developer tools screenshot -- http://idojarasbudapest.hu/archivalt-idojaras]

So perhaps change your code to something like this:

```
import requests

data= {'ev': '2016','ho': '01', 'button': 'Mehet'}
r = requests.post('http://idojarasbudapest.hu/archivalt-idojaras', data=data)

print (r.text)
```

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for that!:)

Answer (score 2):

To your payload, add `'button': 'Mehet'`.

```
data= {'ev': '2016', 'ho': '01', 'button': 'Mehet'}
```

Comment: I have tried this, but that did not solve the problem. What Odysseas mentioned is working.
Thanks!

Comment: @ajlaj25 Oh yeah, I didn't realise, sorry. You have to submit the value of the option, which would be `01` for January. Will edit accordingly.